# Django max post size triggered for small request?

Tags: django

I have some requests triggering this issue...

From my main Apache log:

> [Mon Aug 26 20:03:48.793674 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 50973:tid 140470815614720] [remote 207.136.212.82:60947] ERROR Request body
>   exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.

... and from my access log:

> localhost:443 207.136.212.82 - - [26/Aug/2019:20:03:48 +0000] "POST /en/log HTTP/1.1" 400 539 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"

That 539 bytes should be well below the Django setting:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
from django.conf import settings
settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE
2621440
```

What could be triggering this check for such a small request?

Comment: Have you checked the syntax in your `settings.py` file? It looks as though the string is getting referenced in your logs, which suggests the value is not resolving.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's it - here's source from django/http/request.py:

int(self.META.get('CONTENT_LENGTH') or 0) > settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE):
                raise RequestDataTooBig('Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.')